# From where can I get latest security bug fixes list/details implemented by web browsers?

Tags: web-browser, updates

Every now and then a new vulnerability is discovered in web browsers. Some get fixed with time, some don't (maybe because of dependencies).

From where can I get the report of latest bugs fixed or pending?

Comment: Among others: https://packetstormsecurity.com. As for the unfixed ones you usually don't get these for security reasons unless you are a developer of the project.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is it browser specific?

Comment: @have you actually looked at this site? Its full of security issues not only for but including the browsers. And yes, the development process and publication of issues for the various browsers is browser specific. One reason is that some are closed source while others not.